# Complex conjugate roots of the auxiliary equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I went through a section from the book Mathematical Methods in the Physical Sciences, 3rd ed. (Boas) that stated: suppose the roots of the auxiliary equation are $\alpha\pm\beta i$. Therefore the general of the solution of the differential equation is
$$y=Ae^{\left(\alpha+\beta i\right)x}+Be^{\left(\alpha-\beta i\right)x}=e^{\alpha x}\left(Ae^{i\beta x}+Be^{-i\beta x}\right)\tag1$$
and by substituting $e^{\pm i\beta x}=\cos{\left(\beta x\right)}\pm i\sin{\left(\beta x\right)}$, the parenthesis in Eq. (1) becomes a linear combination of $\sin{\left(\beta x\right)}$ and $\cos{\left(\beta x\right)}$ and can be written as
$$y=e^{\alpha x}\left(c_1\sin{\left(\beta x\right)}+c_2\cos{\left(\beta x\right)}\right)\tag2$$
where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are new arbitrary constants. Eq. (2) can also be written in the form
$$y=ce^{\alpha x}\sin{\left(\beta x+\gamma\right)}\tag3$$
where $c$ and $\gamma$ are now the arbitary constants. My assumption as to writing Eq. (1) in the form of Eq. (2) was that
$$y=e^{\alpha x}\left(A\left(\cos{\left(\beta x\right)}+ i\sin{\left(\beta x\right)}\right)+B\left(\cos{\left(\beta x\right)}- i\sin{\left(\beta x\right)}\right)\right)\tag4$$
but I was stuck with how the parenthesis in Eq. (4) could be written in the form in Eq. (2) and why new arbitrary constants ($c_1$ and $c_2$) were used instead of using $A$ and $B$. I'm also confused as to how Eq. (2) can be rewritten as Eq. (3) and why different arbitrary constant $c$ was used. It was stated that addition trigonometric identity was used. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Expand $(4)$ and constants are ... constants.

Comment: Looks like $c_1=A+B$ and $c_2=i(A-B)$. What is the exact problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're studying a vector space of functions, and writing each such function as a linear combination of the elements of some basis of that vector space. When we work in terms of $e^{\alpha x}\sin\beta x$ and $e^{\alpha x}\cos\beta x$ instead of $e^{(\alpha\pm i\beta)x}$, we change our choice of basis, so the coefficients change. You can think of it as rotating axes. As @JyrkiLahtonen notes, $c_1=i(A-B)$ and $c_2=A+B$. (Well, they had them the other way round, but you did choose $c_1$ as your $e^{\alpha x}\sin\beta x$ coefficient.)

To go from (2) to (3), use the compound angle formula $\sin(\beta x+\gamma)=\cos\gamma\sin\beta x+\sin\gamma\cos\beta x$, so you have to solve $c\cos\gamma=c_1,\,c\sin\gamma=c_2$ using $c^2=c_1^2+c_2^2$. I'll leave the rest to you.

Comment: Ah! I didn't notice that at first. Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

From $(2)$ to $(3)$, we have to use that
$$
\forall (a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2,\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^2,\exists (R,C)\in \mathbb{R}^2, \, a\cos(x) + b\sin(x) = R\cos(x+C)
$$
A different constant was used because of this conversion.
See [here](https://www.intmath.com/analytic-trigonometry/6-express-sin-sum-angles.php) for example.

From $(4)$ to $(2)$, we have
$$
A +B=c_2 \qquad \text{ and } \qquad i(A-B) = c_1
$$

Comment: That makes sense now. Thank you!